# Guardar valor dentro de um while

Tags: java

Preciso armazenar todas as entradas que o usuário fizer na entrada4(pontoinserido) para calcular quantas vezes ele digitou "7", porém no while está somente substituindo a ultima entrada.

```java
System.out.println("Digite quantos pontos o cliente possui. ");
Scanner entrada1 = new Scanner(System.in);

pontos = entrada1.nextInt();

while (contador != pontos) {
    System.out.println("Digite as composição dos pontos, 3,4,5 ou 7 são permitidos ");
    System.out.println("Pontos em análise " + pontos + "  Somátorio dos pontos inseridos  " + contador);
    Scanner entrada4 = new Scanner(System.in);
    pontoinserido = entrada4.nextInt();
                        
    while (pontoinserido != 3 && pontoinserido != 4 && pontoinserido != 5 && pontoinserido != 7) {

        System.out.println("Resposta incorreta. Digite as composição dos pontos, 3,4,5 ou 7 são permitidos.");
        pontoinserido = entrada4.nextInt();
                            

    }

    contador = pontoinserido + contador;

    if (contador > pontos) {
        System.out.println("A somatoria de pontos ultrapassou os pontos, favor refazer a operação");
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Você vai precisar utilizar algum tipo de coleção, como um array ou um `List`, que precisará ser declarado fora do while para armazenar os valores de forma que os mesmos sejam acessíveis após o fim das iterações.

Answer (score 0):

Voce pode declarar um contador, e toda vez que o numero 7 for digitado esse contador ganha um acréscimo.

```
     System.out.println("Digite quantos pontos o cliente possui. ");
Scanner entrada1 = new Scanner(System.in);

int contador = 0;

pontos = entrada1.nextInt();

while (contador != pontos) {
    System.out.println("Digite as composição dos pontos, 3,4,5 ou 7 são permitidos ");
    System.out.println("Pontos em análise " + pontos + "  Somátorio dos pontos inseridos  " + contador);
    Scanner entrada4 = new Scanner(System.in);
    pontoinserido = entrada4.nextInt();
                        
    while (pontoinserido != 3 && pontoinserido != 4 && pontoinserido != 5 && pontoinserido != 7) {
      
        if(pontoinserido == 7){
          contador++;
}


        System.out.println("Resposta incorreta. Digite as composição dos pontos, 3,4,5 ou 7 são permitidos.");
        pontoinserido = entrada4.nextInt();
                            

    }

    contador = pontoinserido + contador;

    if (contador > pontos) {
        System.out.println("A somatoria de pontos ultrapassou os pontos, favor refazer a operação");
        return;
    }
}
```